# Calling Entity Framework code classes from other Entity Framework Controller classes

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework-6

I have a lot of repetitive code in my controllers which I am trying to offload to a shared helper class so that I can update in one place instead of the hundreds where they currently are.

I have extracted the repetitive code to a separate method, but, I couldn't work out how to actually get the data from the database without calling entity framework again.

To give a very rough example, before:

```
class foo{
private MyDbContext db = new MyDbContext();
Public Actionresult test()
{
     ViewModel.bla = db.bla.tolist();
     ... about 6 more lines that are the same on many methods...
     ViewModel.page = db.uniquelogic.tolist();
}
```

after:

```
class foo{
private MyDbContext db = new MyDbContext();
Public Actionresult test()
{
     ViewModel.bla = new dbhelper.getbla();
     ViewModel.page = db.uniquelogic.tolist();
}
```

shared file (bla.cs):

```
class dbhelper{
private MyDbContext db = new MyDbCotnext();
public bla getbla()
{
...logic here
return bla
}
```

So, both methods work here and I prefer using the second as I only have to update it once, but, my question is:

1. Is there anything wrong with calling the DbContext multiple times? I remember with EF 3 (the last time I used this), it caused errors and I was surprised it worked now.
2. In controllers, there is a seprate dispose clause, there is nothing in a standard class that I can call. Is this a problem?
3. Is there a better way to do this? It doesn't "feel" correct, but, I'm unsure what else to do.

Comment: What do you mean by "Is there anything wrong with calling the DbContext multiple times"? Do you mean accessing different members of the same DBContext multiple times, or just instantiating multiple instances of a DbContext?

Comment: you used EF 3, and your surprised that EF 6 can handle this.... Technology does move on. There is a little overhead creating a context each time but it's the recommended approach because it acts as the Unit of Work and Repository. So you should open a new Unit of Work each time you want to retrieve or modify something.

Comment: @Dai - I mean instantiating multiple instances - it feels like a waste, but I don't have the knowledge on how to share/pass it through. What I have works, but, I am trying to learn to be better and it doesn't feel the correct way to do it.

Comment: @CallumLinington hehe - Thanks. I just felt like it wasn't that hard back then either (I can't remember the workaround), but, I just assumed it didn't work for a reason and it wasn't approved or the best way of doing things. I'm happy what I have works, but, I am here to learn and feel there must be a better way of doing things. What you say though is refreshing, I just haven't heard of it before. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Logic common to multiple `Controller` classes could be moved to a base "`BaseController`" class, thus also giving you automatic control over the lifetime of the object too:

```
public abstract class BaseController : Controller {

    private MyDbContext _db;

    protected MyDbContext DBContext {
        get { return _db ?? ( _db = new MyDbContext() ); }
    }

    protected void PopulateViewModel(ViewModel vm) {
        vm.Bla = this.DBContext.GetBla();
        vm.Page = this.DBContext.UniqueLogic.ToList();
    }

    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing) {
        if (disposing && this._db != null) {
            this._db.Dispose();
            this._db = null;
        }
        base.Dispose(disposing);
    }
}
```

Then in your derived controllers:

```
public class SomeAreaController : BaseController {

    public ActionResult Test() {

        ViewModel vm = new ViewModel();
        this.PopulateViewModel( vm );

        // and if you still need access to a DbContext, use the inherited property:
        this.DBContext.DoSomething();

        return this.View( vm );
    }
}
```

Comment: Ideally this will also be used outside of MVC/in a shared library so it can be used elsewhere as well... but, my fault for not saying that... I guess any use outside of a controller will need a significant difference anyway... I absolutely love this approach and never thought about using derived controllers. This is brilliant! :)